# How to remove multiple key:value pair within an array in groovy?

Tags: arrays, json, arraylist, groovy

How to remove/delete key:value pair within a map in groovy?

My code:

```
data.each { val ->
   SKILLS = val.skills
   HOBBY = val.hobby
   VALUE = val
   NEW_MAP = VALUE - (SKILLS + HOBBY)
}
echo "${VALUE}"
echo "${NEW_MAP}"
```

output in ${VALUE}, output in ${NEW_MAP} is null

```
[name: John, skills:[[singing:beginner, dancing:beginner], [java:competent, groovy:beginner]], hobby:[hiking, hockey]]
```

I also tried this but it wont work:

```
def x = SKILLS + HOBBY
NEW_MAP = VALUE.minus(x)
NEW_MAP = VALUE.remove(x)
```

I want to remove the entire skills and hobby. How can I do that?

Comment: If it has key-value pairs, it's a Map, not an Array. Just like in Java, you can remove a key from a Map by calling `map.remove(key)`. Note that this does not create a new object, but rather modifies the object itself.

Comment: It removes it from `val` and returns the removed value. Copying a map: https://www.baeldung.com/java-copy-hashmap

Comment: I need to clone/copy my map?

Comment: depends on your use case, but you have to be aware of the difference

Comment: Btw i also tried **def x=val.remove('skills', 'hobby')** it throws an error as well

Comment: Can you provide an example of `data` and what you would expect the answer to be?  I can't work out what you're after

Comment: data is just the map. And tge expected output should be just **[name:John]** i cant figure out how to rmove the skills and hobby key value pair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine your data is a json, similar to the following structure:

```
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "skill": [
                    {
                        "singing": "beginner",
                        "dancing": "beginner"
                    },
                    {
                        "java": "competent",
                        "groovy": "beginner"
                    }
                ],
                "hobby": [
                    "hiking",
                    "hockey"
                ]
            },
            {
                "skill": [
                    {
                        "singing": "beginner1",
                        "dancing": "beginner1"
                    },
                    {
                        "java": "competent1",
                        "groovy": "beginner1"
                    }
                ],
                "hobby": [
                    "hiking1",
                    "hockey1"
                ],
                "skill": [
                    {
                        "singing": "beginner2",
                        "dancing": "beginner2"
                    },
                    {
                        "java": "competent2",
                        "groovy": "beginner2"
                    }
                ],
                "hobby": [
                    "hiking2",
                    "hockey2"
                ]
            },
            {
                "skill": [
                    {
                        "singing": "beginner3",
                        "dancing": "beginner3"
                    },
                    {
                        "java": "competent3",
                        "groovy": "beginner3"
                    }
                ],
                "hobby": [
                    "hiking3",
                    "hockey3"
                ],
                "skill": [
                    {
                        "singing": "beginner4",
                        "dancing": "beginner4"
                    },
                    {
                        "java": "competent4",
                        "groovy": "beginner4"
                    }
                ],
                "hobby": [
                    "hiking4",
                    "hockey4"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

when you print the above on the console you have what you have pasted in your question.

`[[data:[[skill:[[singing:beginner, dancing:beginner], [java:competent, groovy:beginner]], hobby:[hiking, hockey]], [skill:[[singing:beginner2, dancing:beginner2], [java:competent2, groovy:beginner2]], hobby:[hiking2, hockey2]], [skill:[[singing:beginner4, dancing:beginner4], [java:competent4, groovy:beginner4]], hobby:[hiking4, hockey4]]]]]`

If I understand it correctly what you need, you can try something like the below. Where `dataJson` is the aforementioned json.

```
JsonSlurper js = new JsonSlurper()
def json = js.parseText(dataJson)
println(json)


def newArr = []
json.data[0].each { val ->
    def new_map = [:]
    new_map.SKILL = val.skill
    new_map.HOBBY = val.hobby
    def value = val

    newArr.add(new_map)
    println("\n" + "This is val: " + value)
    println("This is the map: " + new_map.SKILL + ", " + new_map.HOBBY)

}

println("\n\nThis is the newArr: " + newArr)
```

Output:

```
[[data:[[skill:[[singing:beginner, dancing:beginner], [java:competent, groovy:beginner]], hobby:[hiking, hockey]], [skill:[[singing:beginner2, dancing:beginner2], [java:competent2, groovy:beginner2]], hobby:[hiking2, hockey2]], [skill:[[singing:beginner4, dancing:beginner4], [java:competent4, groovy:beginner4]], hobby:[hiking4, hockey4]]]]]

This is val: [skill:[[singing:beginner, dancing:beginner], [java:competent, groovy:beginner]], hobby:[hiking, hockey]]
This is the map: [SKILL:[[singing:beginner, dancing:beginner], [java:competent, groovy:beginner]], HOBBY:[hiking, hockey]]

This is val: [skill:[[singing:beginner2, dancing:beginner2], [java:competent2, groovy:beginner2]], hobby:[hiking2, hockey2]]
This is the map: [SKILL:[[singing:beginner2, dancing:beginner2], [java:competent2, groovy:beginner2]], HOBBY:[hiking2, hockey2]]

This is val: [skill:[[singing:beginner4, dancing:beginner4], [java:competent4, groovy:beginner4]], hobby:[hiking4, hockey4]]
This is the map: [SKILL:[[singing:beginner4, dancing:beginner4], [java:competent4, groovy:beginner4]], HOBBY:[hiking4, hockey4]]


This is the newArr: [[SKILL:[[singing:beginner, dancing:beginner], [java:competent, groovy:beginner]], HOBBY:[hiking, hockey]], [SKILL:[[singing:beginner2, dancing:beginner2], [java:competent2, groovy:beginner2]], HOBBY:[hiking2, hockey2]], [SKILL:[[singing:beginner4, dancing:beginner4], [java:competent4, groovy:beginner4]], HOBBY:[hiking4, hockey4]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for further explaining. But i want to know how to remove  multiple key:value pair and only the **[name:John]** will be returned. How should i do that?

Comment: Depends on your collection, some are immutable, generally you should be able to use ```remove()```.
If your map is immutable create a new one for the old one like:
```def somethingNew = [:] << oldMap```

Comment: Can i delete a multiple key value pair within a map? I tried using .remove() but it returns null